# ASUS Z690 motherboard hangs on boot. Could this be a bad hard drive and SSD combination?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, motherboard

We are using ASUS ProArt Z690-Creator WiFi motherboard and Operating system is ubuntu 22.04. Previously we used AZEK 256GB SSD and 1TB hard drive. It worked okay. Laterly we changed SSD and started using SAMSUNG 980 PRO SSD 2TB(We have checked the SSD is alright). It worked okay.

When we connected a 4TB hard drive(we have checked hard drive is all right) with the following setup following issues begin:

- Sometimes stuck at startup splash screen and doesn't enter into BIOS or continue to boot.
- Sometimes PC boot but hang sometimes.

After issue arises if we try disconnecting hard drive still the problem persist. But if we turned off power for some minutes and start trying sometimes it works and sometimes not. We have tried inserting SSD in different ports and without connecting hard drive it sometimes work and sometimes not.(SSD and Hard drive is working okay in different pc). What are the possible causes for the problem?

Our PC configuration is Intel Core i9-12900K Processor, Corsair VENGEANCE 16GB DDR5 4800MHz C40, dual ASUS ROG Strix GeForce RTX 3090Ti. (Detail on the PC setup is contained in this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ROoXnFt3dVw). As the SSD is damaged we have mentioned in the video, we have changed the SSD previously)

**update** : Our PSU is
(1) Cooler Master MWE Gold 1250W 80 PLUS connected with motherboard and one 3090ti GPU.
(2) ASUS ROG STRIX 1000W Gold connected with one 3090ti GPU and some fans.

We have run some more experiments->
->. We removed both GPU and Hard drive. That works fine. But when we tried to add hard drive again it started stuck at the beggining and issue persist until we totally turned off power supply. If we turned off the power supply and try again after 5-6 minutes later it getting started finely but after working sometimes it gets hanged sometimes.
-> We have tried without hard drive.It is sometimes working well for long time. We can also able to running dual GPU's. But sometimes it gets hanged when we open multiple application and sometimes SSD becoming Read only and get stucked.

Comment: 1. Reset UEFI ("BIOS") and test. 2. UPDATE UEFI. Also make sure the OS is properly installed in UEFI mode.

Comment: In general you bring it down to it's minimum config to get it to boot. If it boots, start adding components one-by-one. If you ID suspect component, go back and change order so you can determine it's actually the suspect component and not insufficient power or something.

Comment: Is it possible that the power supply (PSU) is no longer sufficient after your additions?

Comment: We have tried excluding our GPU's and hard drive, that works fine. But when we try to install Hard drive again the problem begins.(In that cofiguration we have tried the combination Cooler Master MWE Gold 1250W 80 PLUS power suppy is connected with motherboard and hard drive.)